How do romantic relationships in books work?
Now, I'm not asking this as in a "I'm new to writing and I want a tutorial" but more in a "I'm aromantic, have never had any crushes, and I have little to no knowledge on how romance works."
I don't want the romance to feel like some strange friendship/uncanny valley type thing.

A gentle reminder that comments are for suggesting improvements to the question, not for querying its subject matter.

Basically this questions comes down to: I want to write about something with which I have no personal experience, but I want to make it realistic. How do I do so? And the answer is always the same:
Research!

Find a good book that explains romantic love with as much detail as you want.
Very briefly, romantic love can be thought of as a combination of several needs: the need to belong (a friendship is more loose and less binding than committing to a romantic relationship where there usually is some kind of explicit agreement that "now we are together"), sexual desire (which isn't commonly a part of most other relationships in most cultures), a desire for exclusivity (usually of sex, but also of entrusted information), a common life project (including building a common home, procreation, and caring for the common offspring) and so on.

Talk to experts (in this case, people in romantic relationships) and observe them.

Make the rest up.



I don't understand, though, why, as an aromantic person, you would want to write about a type of relationship that has no meaning to you. Why don't you write a story that you can relate to? There are many stories without romantic love, and many readers who don't want to read about it.

"I don't understand, though, why, as an aromantic person, you would want to write about a type of relationship that has no meaning to you." That... Is the correct response. And the answer is actually inside the synopsis of said book. I don't normal write romances.

@qwertykeyboard I can think of many reasons why one would want to write about things that he has not personally experienced. Maybe he find it interesting. Like, I'd guess that most writers of murder mysteries have never murdered anyone. He may feel that it will help sell the story. Even if I'M not interested, maybe most of my potential readers are.

I'm reminded of an article I once read by a science fiction writer who said that he was criticized for writing a story set in a small town, even though he had spent his entire life in New York City. He said he apparently didn't learn the lesson, because he went on to write many stories set on other planets, which he'd never been to either.

@Jay But those writers know fear and apprehension as well as hate and cold calculation (for the murder mystery) or curiosity and the wonder and excitement when faced with something new, for example while travelling to exotic places (that can be transferred to alien planets) or they have been to a big city despite living in a small one (so are familiar with it). All of this is not quite the same as writing about an emotion you don't feel.

Well, sure, writing about a place you've never been to is not the same as writing about an emotion that you don't feel. That's why I'd call what I said an analogy and not exactly the same thing. But if the question is, How can I write about this thing I've never experienced?, both writers are in the same boat. And in any case, the impulse to commit murder is presumably fueled by hate. So as I've never committed a murder, presumably I have never felt that level of hatred. It's an emotion that I don't feel. If I was going to write about a murderer I might consider a time I disliked someone ...

... and try to imagine what it would be like if that dislike was multiplied enough to make me consider murder. But you could say the same about the OP. I don't know his life story, but has he never had a friend that he liked? So multiply that like and that might resemble love. Etc.

@Jay I disagree. A little hatred ≈ a lot of hatred. Friendship (philia) ≠ romantic love (eros). Also, most people don't read murder mysteries because they enjoy imagining what it might feel like to murder someone. They are intrigued by the puzzle! And most murder mysteries don't even portray the murderer during his deed, because the murderer is usually not the protagonist and the murder has already happened. It is therefore not even necessary to be familiar with that feeling. You really are comparing apples to oranges here.

I'm not sure what you're trying to prove. That "writing about something outside your own experience" has different types and degrees? I suppose that's true. Like, I've never been to South Dakota, but I've been to North Dakota and other states in the region, so I could probably write a story that catches the feel of the place. I've also never been to Nigeria, but I think I'd have a much harder time writing a story set in Nigeria than one set in South Dakota. So RE murder mysteries, okay, let's suppose the story is not about the murder itself about the detective solving it. ...

I'd guess most writers of murder mysteries have never worked as detectives for the police department or a private detective agency. They probably base the story more on their general experience in logic and deduction than any experience specific to solving crimes. Is romantic love something totally different from friendship, or is it more like friendship times 10? One could debate such things endlessly.

@Jay You fail to grasp the decisive difference. Most writers have experienced all the things that a detective experiences during his work: being intent on solving a problem, being tired from being overworked, being afraid etc. So it is easy to understand what it means to work as a detective once you learn what it entails. But some few people never experience certain emotions. For example, there is a family whose members never experience fear; some people cannot see certain colors; etc. [contd.]

@Jay [contd.] These people cannot fathom what it means to be afraid, percieve colors etc., because this lies completely outside their experience and they have no experience that is similar enough. Of course these people can write about fear, colors etc., but they will just mimic the words of others and never understand what they refer to.

@Ben If I'm willing to lookup Osama Bin Laden's decrees for my Rats of NIMH fanfiction for the purpose of getting a better understanding of 9/11, then I think it's perfectly reasonable for me too put in a similar amount of effort for writing a half decent romance.

@ben Let me give an example. I lived in the US for 64 years but now live in the Philippines. If before I moved here I had tried to write a story set in the Philippines I would likely have gotten many things wrong. For example, I didn't know that shopping malls here routinely include a grocery store and you go to the mall to buy your groceries. I didn't know that you pay for taxi fare with an app on your cell phone. Etc etc. I might have done research and learned these things, but the problem is, I wouldn't even have known to ask the question. ...

... Someone who has never experienced romantic love would have a very similar problem writing a romance novel. He could do research to find out what people in love do, but would he even know to ask the right questions? To say it's fundamentally different because he's never felt the emotion ... so what? I'd never personally experienced going to the mall to buy groceries. Yes, the two issues are different, but for the writer, they present the same problem.
